# Why don't I see anything on the screen (external build)?

Tags: computer-building

I'm building a computer for the first time, and I have the motherboard outside the case and have it connected to a monitor.

I have the power supply, CPU+fan, and RAM hooked up to the motherboard.

Specs:

- CPU: Core i5 3570k with stock hsf
- mobo: ASRock Z77 Extreme4
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance 8GB (2x4GB)
- PSU: Rosewill Hive 650 W

I'm not using any discrete graphics card yet. I plan to buy one later on when I have the money. Currently I want to use the i5's onboard integrated graphics, but I don't see anything when I hit the power button on the screen. The CPU fan and PSU fans start up and that's it.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you have both the 24-pin and the **4-pin** power connectors installed from the PSU to the motherboard?

Comment: crap, I forgot about the 4 pin. I thought you would only use that if you had a video card. lol I gotta go find out where the 4 pin goes now. I'll comment if it work or not.

Comment: right next to the CPU. Thats a remarkably common error. @sawdust - you might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, that was part of the problem. I still don't see anything load up on screen. Also, now my motherboard is giving an error code (not on screen, on the mobo): 53 which means "memory initialization error. No usable memory detected" according to the manual. I installed the ram like the manual said.

Comment: @sawdust - you should post your comment as an answer. You get rep credit and it will lower the unanswered questions. (By one anyway.lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have both the 24-pin and the **4-pin** power connectors installed from the PSU to the motherboard.  With the mess of wires from the PSU, it's rather easy to overlook the second connector.  I'll admit to forgetting to plug in the 4-pin power connector on more than one occasion.

Hope you are taking adequate anti-static precautions when handling electronic components, especially memory modules.  If you are not using an anti-static wrist strap, then at least discharge yourself by touching grounded metal before handling components, and then try not to move around (which could generate a new static charge).